# Trying to count the lines of text that is printed when reading a file using C programming language

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013

I got a question from my Lecture I am in my first year and I can't solve this question

The Question is trying to ask me to create a program that read the text in a text file and output it in the console and count the lines being printed and see it on the console with outputted text?

Here is the pdf link for the actual question.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0jqSF8uVDH3MHE3S2FhaHhWMXM/view

Here is the link to text file I am reading and outputting in the console.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0jqSF8uVDH3WFBsdExaLXY4RDA/view

Here is the code I made and there is a error i have to removing the actually text output to make it which I don't want to do that.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int current = 0;
    FILE* p_file = 0;

    char name[100];

    printf("what file\n");
    scanf("%s", &name);

    p_file = fopen(name, "r");

    current = fgetc(p_file);

    int count = 0;

    while (EOF != current)
    {
        count = count + 1;

        printf("%d:  ", count);
        printf("%c", current);

        current = fgetc(p_file);

    }
    fclose(p_file);

    return 0;
}
```

Please any read the question and see if you can help

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: Why are people voting down the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could work for you.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE* p_file = 0;
    char name[100];
    char st[100];

    printf("what file\n");
    scanf("%s", name);

    p_file = fopen(name, "r");

    int count = 0;

    while (fgets(st, sizeof st, p_file) != NULL)
    {
        count = count + 1;

        printf("%d:  ", count);
        printf("%s", st);
    }
    fclose(p_file);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to count lines.  So you'll need to check for line endings.  Lines always end with a newline character '\n' and (optionally) a carriage return '\r'.  So, let's count newlines.

Reading byte by byte will be slow, but ok for your level.

```
while (!feof(p_file)) // check for end of file. (EOF != current) that way has not been in use for ages.
{
  // get a byte from file
  current = fgetc(p_file);
  // is it a newline ?
  if (current == '\n')
  {
    ++count;                       // count
    printf("\nline %d :", count);  // only print the line # on a new line. 
                                   // the \n - our current character, is
                                   // printed as part of the line label.
  }
  else
  {
    printf("%c", current);
  }
}
```

That's pretty much it.  Your code does need a bit of error checking after opening the file, make sure all is well and dandy before doing anything with p_File.  And you'll probably want to insert a line # in from of the first line, maybe starting from 1, instead of zero, I'll leave that to you.

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    FILE *fp;
    char filename[FILENAME_MAX+1] = "";
    int line_no, line_no_width, ch, pre_ch;

    printf("Filename? ");fflush(stdout);
    fgets(filename, sizeof filename, stdin);
    filename[strcspn(filename, "\n")] = 0;//chomp newline
    putchar('\n');
    if((fp = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL){
        perror("fopen:");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    line_no = 0;
    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF){
        if(ch == '\n'){
            ++line_no;
        }
        pre_ch = ch;
    }
    if(pre_ch != '\n')
        ++line_no;
    for(line_no_width = 0; line_no; line_no /= 10)
        ++line_no_width;

    line_no = 0;
    pre_ch = '\n';
    rewind(fp);
    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF){
        if(pre_ch == '\n'){
            ++line_no;
            printf("%*d: ", line_no_width, line_no);
        }
        putchar(ch);
        pre_ch = ch;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    if(pre_ch != '\n')
        putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `unsigned long long` for `line_no` ? Who will read such a source? :/

Comment: @Binary_10 Sorry, I'm not sure what you want to ask me.

Comment: It may not have ended with a newline. And as long as it ends with a newline, there is nothing wrong.

Comment: @Binary_10  Are you asking about `if(pre_ch != '\n') putchar('\n');` ? This is simply a bonus as it is not included in the problem setting. It is to prevent the display from being distorted depending on the shell.

Comment: Should use `snprintf` instead of `sprintf`, Although `snprintf` can not be used probably on MSVC, `_snprintf` or `_snprintf_s` can be used instead.